# How to read COM ports? navigator.serial.getPorts returns empty list

Tags: google-chrome

I have a small number of USB serial interfaces connected (a HF transceiver, CW keyer based on Arduino) and two bluetooth ports, that I never use and am not sure where do they come from (probably some application). In my SPA I need to read list of ports to be able to select which one to connect as which function.

However, when I call `navigator.serial.getPorts()` I always get an empty list. BTW, same for `navigator.usb.getDevices()` It runs on Chrome version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (64-bit). Serial API is enabled.

How to solve this?

UPDATE: it is invoked from script in HTML file in local filesystem (not served over HTTP)

Comment: Note: for debugging serial/usb devices in chrome/chromium, you can access `chrome://device-log/` (a.k.a. `about:device-log`)

Comment: also see https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/12576972

Comment: for those using chromium on ubuntu: see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1905458 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/75773169

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to request the user's permission to read the Serial's ports by first calling `navigator.serial.requestPort()`:

```js
onclick = async () => {

  await navigator.serial.requestPort();
  console.log( await navigator.serial.getPorts() );

};
```

[Live example](https://shadow-relic-margin.glitch.me/)

Comment: This does not make much sense to me. First, I need to discover which ports are available and then I would open the port. There is no reason first to connect the port and "discover" it is already there. I don't understand the logic. BTW there seem to be many other design flasw in this API, for instance, it is not possible to verify connection status (is the port open or not), check current baudrate etc. Plus the reader does not work either... I don't quite understand why is this API advertised if it is basically useless and there is no feedback channel to contact designers.

Comment: I tested it using the example provided. Interestingly, even after selecting a port, it still returns empty list. And the example for `getPorts() ` in the API documentation is inconsistent with this answer - it seems to be supposed to do what I originally expected, i.e. list available ports before I decide to access one https://wicg.github.io/serial/#example-2

Comment: I didn't took part in the authoring of this spec, if you want to make your voice heard, they have a [github repo](https://github.com/wicg/serial/) Then you misread the example there, the preamble paragraph states "***Once a site has permission to access a port** it can receive these events and query for the set of connected devices it currently has access to.*". Finally, did you select one such port from the popup on my live example? Weird you have nothing, definitely works for me.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that sentence. Permission has been granted long time ago, it is from in a HTML file from local filesystem. I will try if it changes when it is served from localhost. However, blocking an HTML page from local filesystem from accessing local COM port, that would be too much I guess :)

Comment: That's probably the issue here. You need a `SecureContext` and `file://`  isn't.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it is accurate. On the other hand, the API itself does not make much sense to me. What especially annoys me is that I seem not be able to read data from the port (`await reader.read()` never seems to read anything although the device should be sending some data back). That would be another question/issue. I am so disgusted...

Comment: I modified your example to display for myself the absurdity of the API:
```btn.onclick = async () => {

  await navigator.serial.requestPort();
  let p = await navigator.serial.getPorts()
  console.log(p);
  for ( let pp of p ) {
    const info = await pp.getInfo()
    console.log(info)
  }
};```
It lists two ports, both having identical usbVendorId = 1027 and usbProductId = 25477 (two identical chips in two different devices). Already posted issue on github, but knowing the american devs' attitude, I remain highly skeptical.

Comment: My last comment :) 
If, in your example, I put `navigator.serial.getPorts()` first (before calling `navigator.serial.requestPort()`) and display the same page again, it already shows the ports previously permitted. At least this works as expected. Anyway, thank you once more for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get permission to access any serial port by `Serial.requestPort()`. And the `requestPort` function can be called only with user activation, such as in `click` event callback.

After you get the permission of many serial ports, you can list the ports that you can access by `Serial.getPorts()`.

`getPorts` function doesn't mean get the permission to serial ports, but lists the serials ports that **you have had permission** to access.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Serial