# web serial api shows "no compatible devices found" despite being given the vendorId

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, arduino, web-serial-api

Windows 8.1, Chrome v91.0.4472.164. I have verified the vendor and product ids against the device manager. The device is a Arduino UNO using the Ch340 driver, it is listed in the device manager under Ports(COM & LPT) as "USB-SERIAL CH340(COM7)"
My code looks like this;

```
    try {
        const requestOptions = {
            filters: [{
                usbVendorId: 0x1A86,
                usbProductId: 0x7523
            }]
        };
        const device = await navigator.serial.requestPort(requestOptions);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65715669

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if `usbProductId` and `usbVendorId` are wrong somehow ;(

Can you try this snippet of code which will allow you to get a prompt, select the Arduino UNO device serial port, and check `usbProductId` and `usbVendorId`?

```js
const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
const { usbProductId, usbVendorId } = port.getInfo();
console.log({ usbProductId, usbVendorId });
```