# chromium on ubuntu serial web api no compatible devices found

Tags: ubuntu, arduino, chromium, web-serial-api

I want to use web serial api in chromium to be able to communicate with Arduino, however I get the message no compatible devices found.
When I use Arduino IDE or python I can find it, but with chromium no.

UBUNTU DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
Chromium 111.0.5563.64 snap

```
let port = await navigator.serial.requestPort({});
```

Is it possible to fix the issue to get all serial ports

I tried to reinstall chromium but no success

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68517934

Comment: Possibly caused by this bug, currently open: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1905458 (also see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1890365)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem installing WLED using Chromium snap on Ubuntu over Web Serial (https://install.wled.me/).  I was able to do it by re-configuring Chromium with the command:

```
sudo snap connect chromium:raw-usb
```

Comment: for those interested in what `snap connect` actually does: https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management and https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement

Comment: and to see existing connections, you can use `snap connections chromium`

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall snap version of Chrome and install from [Google Chrome website](https://www.google.com/chrome/?platform=linux). I am able to get all ports with this version of Chrome Browser.